# Unable to sign APK after migrating from IntelliJ to Android Studio (or password problem?)

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, apk

I recently switched back to Android Studio after a few months of trying out the Android plugin of IntelliJ.
Then I tried signing the APK of an app that is currently in beta test in the play store but the signature does not match what is on the Dev Play Console for the previous versions.
I double checked and I am sure that I am using the same keystore (and same key) as before.

Now I am left with two possibilities:

• There's a problem of code signing when migrating IntelliJ to Android?

• My passwords for the keystore are wrong. But then, why would it succeed in building the APK?

Can I rule out any of these two directions?

It reads on the Google help that if the keystores are lost (which is not the case, but maybe the password is), one need to recreate a completely new app on the Play Store with a new package name.

There really would be no alternative to this?

PS: I had downloaded some certificates for apk signing in the past, but I don't know how to use them within Android studio in stead of the jks files.

**EDIT**

The error message I get from the store is :

```
 You uploaded an APK that is not signed with the upload certificate. 
 You must use the same certificate. The upload certificate has fingerprint:

 [ SHA1: XXX ]
 and the certificate used to sign the APK you uploaded have 
 fingerprint:
 [ SHA1: YYY ]
```

Yet, when I run the following:

```
 keytool -list -v -keystore "/Path/upload_keystore.jks" 
 -alias "upload_key" -storepass ***** -keypass ****
```

I get that the SHA1 is actually **XXX** (and not **YYY**).
So it should be right.
Also, weird thing: whatever passwords I use, I get the same SHA1, and it is the correct one!

But I also get the following message:

```
Warning:
The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to 
migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using "keytool 
-importkeystore -srckeystore /Path/upload_keystore.jks - 
 destkeystore /Path/upload_keystore.jks -deststoretype pkcs12".
```

Which is weird since it was generated by Google.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I just did a clean build, and signed it again, and it worked.
I guess the first signing attempt was wrong, but it got cached and prevented the other signing attempts to really be effective.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up! I'll file a bug in Android Studio to get that fixed.

Comment: Actually I was not able to reproduce. Whenever I changed the signingConfig in the gradle file, a bar appears asking me to sync, and after syncing and regenerating the APK, the APK is signed with the new keystore correctly. Do you remember doing a particular course of action that didn't require you syncing the new gradle config?

Comment: To be honest, I think the signingConfig hasn't been working for me for years. I had always to register the password using the UI of Android Studio or IntelliJ. Also, now that the problem is solved, I can't reproduce it either...